# Is what I have done long ago, kufr?

Tags: kufr

When I was 9 years old, I was with some of my non-believer friends and one had a packet of Haribo (a haram food). I didn’t like being left out, so I asked for one, saying to my friends that it didn’t have gelatin in it (also a haram food). Since I knew that this was wrong, does this mean it’s kufr?

I have only thought about it now, many years later, and cannot tell if it is kufr or not. I have looked around for answers, but can’t find any and I’m really unsure. If this is kufr, can I have it forgiven?

Comment: Please edit your post and elaborate on the reason that make you think this would be kufr? As there's no link to it that can be concluded from what you've posted so far.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Taqwa on another level :'D. No this does not make you in the least bit a Kaafir. You sinned, and all sins can be forgiven, except Shirk (associating partners with Allah) and you haven't committed Shirk. May Allah guide you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kufr is meant for to refuse,to disbeleive.A things that is described Haram in the Quran & if u take it as acceptable(Halal) to u that is Kufr.If u have no idea about ur deed either it Haram or Halal then Allah is Gafuur.
U asked for Haribo at 9 yrs old & i predict then ur such knowledge was not developed either this is haram or not.
Now u are thinking that what u did was haram.
If u didn’t this knowledge then that was not kufr.But as u were involving with haram,u had better repent to Allah  & sick for His forgiveness(Tawbah).

Again if u had knowledge that what u were doing was wrong that is close to Kufr.Actually Kufr is matther of beleif.
Doing wrong,i think is not,But Taking this wrong deed right for urself in spite of having knowledge of it is concerned with Kufr.

But Doing wrong having righteous mind is concerning.
Ur repeated such work may promote ur subconscious mind to take forbidden things as acceptable to urself that is Kufr.

Now,if u are concerned with kufr for anytime of ur lifespan and presently u can term it as Kufr then make Tawbah  and seek from Allah to remain u at the way of Hidaith.Allah is Gafuur.Many Sahabi who were Kaffir at a certain time,became good muslim later & shouldn’t we follow them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Kufr for two reasons:

1) You believed it to be wrong

2) You were nine years old. You are not accountable until you've reached the age of puberty. (I'm assuming you had not at that age).